# How to delete values of redis hashmap key

Tags: redis

I have created a key called `key1` which contains `Firstname`, `Lastname` and `Age`.

I want to delete all the fields created under `key1` but not the key. What command do I need to use to delete all the fields and their value?

My hashmap `key1` contains `Firstname`, `Lastname` and `Age`. I want to delete all the fields (`Firstname`, `Lastname`, and `Age`). I tried using -

`HDEL key1 Firstname`

It worked but I have to do one at a time.I am looking for a command which deletes all fields at a time.

I expect all the fields to be deleted at once but the key should remain in Redis.

Answer (score 2):

It is definitely **not possible**

Because Redis creates Hash when 1st item is inserted and delete the hash when  last item is removed. It is not possible to keep an empty hash structure in redis.

For more info [redis-doesn't-store-empty-hashes](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2965-redis-doesn-t-store-empty-sets-or-hashes-and-will-delete-empty-sets-and-hashes.htm)

Comment: Correct. And, to answer the OPs question, the command to delete all fields from a Hash is `DEL` :)